# jquery onclick toggle nearest UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to toggleClass the nearest #dropdown element using jQuery and I can't seem to find the ul. jQuery is loading fine and each element acknowledges the click.

HTML code is:

```
<li onclick="showDropDown()" class="filter-button">
                            Filter by <strong>Aread</strong> +
    <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="">Test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery code is:

```
  function showDropDown() {
    jQuery(this).parents("li").find("ul").toggleClass('show');
  }
```

Comment: no need for `.parents("li")` your click event is in the li already all you need is find the ul inside the li.

Comment: try to use jQuery(this).children instead of parents.

Comment: I think your code is not complete, try to make a fiddle or explain better, you are searching for $(this).parents but in your html there isn't the UL parent of the li#dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropdown` ul is the child element of `filter-button` li. So you dont need to find the parent here

```
$(".filter-button").click(function() {
  $(this).find("ul").toggleClass('show');
});
```

OR,

If you really need to use the inline method calling then you need to pass the current object as well,

```
<li onclick="showDropDown(this)" class="filter-button">
```

code,

```
function showDropDown(obj) {
  jQuery(obj).find("ul").toggleClass('show');
}
```

Comment: Yes.. _Perfect!_ I was about to suggest the same :)

Answer (score 1):

If there are many UL elements as child and nextSibling, you have to write as below.

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/nigayo/Lo3yf31y/1/

[JavaScript]

```
      $(".filter-button").click(function() {
        $(this).find("ul:first").toggleClass('show');
        $(this).next("ul:first").toggleClass('show');
      });
```

[HTML]

```
  <li class="filter-button">
    Filter by <strong>Aread</strong> +
    <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <ul id="dropdown_next" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="dropdown_next2" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing `this` object in the `method` call.

Refer the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/ngdnoyey/).

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="showDropDown(this)" class="filter-button">
    Filter by <strong>Aread</strong> +
    <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="">Test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
function showDropDown(obj) {
  $(obj).find("ul").toggle();
}
```